# How do I get dbeaver to show the caret and table size

Tags: dbeaver

I am using dbbeaver Version 21.1.2.202107041908 on a mac.  Yes.

Once upon a time there would be a ">" next to the word Tables and when I clicked it, all the tables would show with their size in mb next to them.  This is no longer the case, instead the caret disappears when I click on it.  When I double click public I get all the tables in another window and they're fine.  I think I might have accidentally turned this feature off somehow.  I've tried searching everything like "autoupdate" or "expand branches" or some such.  It would be best to fix this, but short of that, what's the right vocabulary to investigate this issue?

[image: dbbeaver picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: embarrassing picture]

If you have letters above the elephant and it doesn't relate to the name of any object in the folder, the carets will disappear.  Can I just also say this was not a feature on pgadmin3 so it's not a solid picnic.